# Best way to handle curator SUSPEND state from ConnectionStateListener

Tags: apache-zookeeper, apache-curator

I want to ask a question about handling SUSPEND state.

Here is the background:

I am using curator/zk to as a task coordinator for a list of concurrent running jobs.
For every minute, every worker (each work run on a separate VM) try to acquire a task (lock) from zk by calling:

```
lock = new InterProcessSemaphoreMutex(zkClient, task); 
boolean hasLock = false;
hasLock = lock.acquire(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

If the work get the lock, it will do the task.

The class which is responsible for retriever lock/task implement ConnectionStateListener interface. And below is the currently implementation:

- **RECONNECT**: do nothing, since worker will try to acquire lock
  regardless the ZK connection status.
- **LOST**: release the lock, since the connect is lost.
- **SUSPEND**: ??????

My question is about SUSPEND state, should I release the lock when enter SUSPEND (basically, treat as lost) or do something else?

What is the best practice to handle SUSPEND state?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2):

I guess you have seen the comment at the end of this [page](http://curator.apache.org/curator-recipes/shared-lock.html).

> It is strongly recommended that you add a ConnectionStateListener and
>   watch for SUSPENDED and LOST state changes. **If a SUSPENDED state is
>   reported you cannot be certain that you still hold the lock unless you
>   subsequently receive a RECONNECTED state.** If a LOST state is reported
>   it is certain that you no longer hold the lock.

I interpret this as: you hold the lock until you receive a `RECONNECTED` state, unless your connection is `LOST` and the lock is released.